# Unspecified error -2147467259 when parsing XML

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, com+

I'm getting the error "unspecified error" when I'm parsing an XML that contains a base64 string (file.pdf). When I don't sent the base64 string the XML is accepted and I get the response I need. It's not like the base64 string is wrong, because I tested the string and the result is alright.

Below the VBScript that I use and a part of the XML.

VBScript:

```vb
Dim xmlDoc
Dim oHTTP
Dim Information
Dim strAuth
Dim PutDeliveryRequest
Dim terug
Dim doc
Dim xmlString
Dim IssuerAssignedID
Dim aParts, aCredentials, strType, strBase64, strPlain, strUser, strPassword, alles, sitenaam, brealmN, ivbId
'strAuth = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
'alles =  Request.ServerVariables("ALL_HTTP")
Set oHTTP = Server.CreateObject("DllLib.GetDataFromDB")
sitenaam  = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") 

If sitenaam = "soap.fbt.vgsoftware.nl" Then
    brealmN ="Fbt" '----------een ivb
    ivbId = 1
    IssuerAssignedID = "8719604178115"
End If

If sitenaam = "soap.bwals.vgsoftware.nl" Then
    brealmN ="BWals" '----------een ivb
    ivbId = 2
    IssuerAssignedID = "8719604094330"
End If

If sitenaam = "soap.bvh.vgsoftware.nl" Then
    brealmN ="Baltus" '----------een ivb enz enz
    ivbId=3
    IssuerAssignedID = "3333"
End If

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "false"
xmlDoc.Load(Request)

If xmldoc.ParseError <> 0 Then '--------------------------------foute xml ,
    response.Write "<?xml version=""1.0"" ?><env:Envelope xmlns:env=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><env:Body><Error><Message>"& xmldoc.ParseError.Reason &  " " & xmldoc.ParseError.ErrorCode & "</Message></Error></env:Body></env:Envelope>"
    response.End
Ind If

If (oHTTP.CheckUsers(xmlDoc.Xml) = True) Then
    xmlString = oHTTP.StringXml(xmlDoc.Xml, sitenaam, IssuerAssignedID) 
    Response.Write xmlString
Else
    Response.Write "<?xml version=""1.0"" ?><env:Envelope xmlns:env=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><env:Body><Error><Message>Gebruiker niet geauthorizeerd.</Message></Error></env:Body></env:Envelope>"
End If
```

Xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <PutOrderRequest xmlns="http://www.edibulb.nl/XML/Order:2" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ebram="urn:ebl:edibulb:xml:data:draft:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.edibulb.nl/XML/Order:2 http://www.edibulb.nl/XML/Order/Order-2_00.xsd">
      <body>
        <OrderDocument>
          <ebram:NameText>kb_1054595.pdf</ebram:NameText>
          <ebram:AttachedBinaryFile>
            <ebram:FileName>kb_1054595.pdf</ebram:FileName>
            <ebram:IncludedBinaryObject mimeCode="application/pdf" encodingCode="7">JVBERi0xLjMKJbe+raoKMSAwIG9iago8PAovUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIKL1...
           </ebram:IncludedBinaryObject>
          </ebram:AttachedBinaryFile>
        </OrderDocument>
      </Body>
    </PutOrderRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Update 1**

the tags that missed was an error in this question. but the error remains.

the error is produced only in a few base64 strings formed from pdf.

when creating a pdf in word 2010 the string is accepted but a pdf generated from another program gives this error.

**Update 2**

Problem is a step closer of being solved.

It need some testing but apparently its the soap server that cant handle the size of the base64 file send inside of the xml.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error with the XML sample you posted (after fixing the obvious syntax errors). Please provide sample input that allows us to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers: how can i send an Base64 string for reproduce purposes when the max characters is about 30K and the base64 string is around 600K characters

Comment: Reduce the string to a smaller sample that still exposes the behavior. How do you expect us to help when we can't even reproduce, much less analyze, the problem?